# How to auto run a Class on startup

Tags: jsp

I have a webapplication that relies on some initialization (ie some threads needs to be started).

something like:

```
public Class Init {
   private static resource ....
   static {
      // my initialization
   }

   public static void init(){}
}
```

So I putted all my initialization stuff in the **Init** *class* and in every jsp page I have to call the **.init()** method... The init method is empty, his purpose is starting the Init Class initialization. This is what I thought to have my initialization started only once.

But I still have to manually call the .init() method in any page (or servlet)... the first page called (that has this initialization) will do what needed and after this point every other page is secured ('cause the resources are already initialized). But this has a week spot, if I miss one page, and an user calls that page...

Is there a way to instruct Tomcat to execute my initialization automatically after application start-up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of a `ServletContextListener`. Have your `Init` class implement this interface. You may if you like move your initialization code from static block to `contextInitialized()` method.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class Init implements ServletContextListener {

  private static resource;

  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    // your initialization
  }

  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) { 
    // empty  
  }
}
```

Please note that you need to register the listener with Tomcat by adding the following into your `web.xml`

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>package.path.to.Init</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Since, you now also have access to the `ServletContext` (call sce.getServletContext()) you can (if choose to) register anything as a context attribute and make it available to any servlet or JSP within your application.